# How to get the 3 objects with a larger value than the other elements of the array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array made up of objects. Each object has two properties: name, value.

```
array = [
 {
  name: 'name1',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name2',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name3',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name4',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name5',
  value: 3
 },
 {
  name: 'name6',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name7',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name8',
  value: 1
 },
 ...
]
```

How do I get objects with the highest value property?
In the above example I should restitute objects that have `value = 4`, `value = 3`, `value = 2` (i.e. the first 3 largest values)
i have tried something like this:

```
let first: 0
let second: 0
let third: 0
array.map((res: any) => {
    if (res.value > first) {
    third = second
    second = first
    first = res
} else if (res.value > second) {
    third = second
    second = res

} else if (res.value > third) {
    third = res
}
})
```

The problem is that if there are two or more objects with the same value, it does not return them both, but only one.

Comment: Why not sort then take the `x` number of highest?

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value).slice(0, 3)`

Comment: nobody has mentioned deduplication

Comment: `.slice` will give just 3 elements. He needs all the elements with top 3 values.

Comment: @Archie array is being sorted first.

Comment: @Tuna yes it will just give top 3 elements. But there could be more than one elements sharing the highest value and in that case there would be more than 3 elements user would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort the array first and then find all the elements containing top 3 values. For that you might need to keep an array checking if you have pushed all the elements containing the same value or not.

```
var pickedValues = [];
array = array
  .sort((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1)
  .filter(el => {
    if(pickedValues.length === 3 && !pickedValues.includes(el.value)) return false;

    if(!pickedValues.includes(el.value)) pickedValues.push(el.value);

    return true;
  });
```

Check the working code below:

```js
var array = [{
    name: 'name1',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'name4',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'name5',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'name6',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'name7',
    value: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'name8',
    value: 1
  },
];

var pickedValues = [];
array = array
  .sort((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1)
  .filter(el => {
    if(pickedValues.length === 3 && !pickedValues.includes(el.value)) return false;
    
    if(!pickedValues.includes(el.value)) pickedValues.push(el.value);
    
    return true;
  });
  
  
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it in detail.

```
let array = [
 {
  name: 'name1',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name2',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name3',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name4',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name5',
  value: 3
 },
 {
  name: 'name6',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name7',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name8',
  value: 1
 }];

let sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.value > b.value) { return -1 };
    if(a.value < b.value) { return 1 };

    return 0;
});

console.table(array.splice(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to sort the array, you can use the default [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, why we have taken the copy using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax is basically we don't want to mutate the existing array.

Once you sort you can do a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which will give you the required elements.

See the working code snippet

```js
let array = [
 {
  name: 'name1',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name2',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name3',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name4',
  value: 4
 },
 {
  name: 'name5',
  value: 3
 },
 {
  name: 'name6',
  value: 2
 },
 {
  name: 'name7',
  value: 0
 },
 {
  name: 'name8',
  value: 1
 }
]

let sortedArray = [...array].sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value)

// now the array is sorted on descending now you can choose the first three or how much i require


console.log(sortedArray.slice(0,3))
```